# how can i find the iframe id by element of body

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I know the element only in html, how to get iframe using paragraph element.

```js
var elm = document.getElementById('parelm');
// I want the <iframe> element
```

```html
<iframe id='iframe_id'>
        <html>
            <body>many content here
                <p> first paragrash </p>
                <p id="parElm"> second paragraph</p>
            </body>
        </html>
</iframe>
```

Comment: `I want the <iframe> element` ... its ID is `iframe_id` ... also, `parelm` is not the same as `parElm` ... and finally, from which  document (main or iframe) are you trying to "get" the `<iframe>` element?

Comment: just do it: `var elm = document.getElementById('iframe_id');`

Comment: i don't know iframe element id, i know only p tag id(**parElm**).

Answer (score 0):

Solution in Javascript

```
var elm = document.getElementById('parelm');
var iframe = elm.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
```

You can do this in jQuery as simple below.

```
var elm = $('#parelm');
var iframe = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
```

Comment: after HTML tag **parent()** function is get null value.